# Setting cookie by PHP and reading using JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cookies, laravel

I use the Laravel PHP framework and set a cookie using Cookie::put(..),

Code to set cookie using Laravel PHP,

```
Cookie::put('id', $id , 0, '/');
```

when I looked into it I found cookie is being set to a root path that's good for me.

Now in JS I use a jQuery plugin to read the cookie but it returns null while reading cookie setted by PHP.

JS code to access cookie,

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
   var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
   for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
   {
     x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
     y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
     x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
     if (x==c_name){
         return unescape(y);
     }
    }
 }
```

print_r($_COOKIE)

```
 Array ( [id] => 653a8dbd0903d2eacfdfe87bce29640d136a4380+1 [session_payload] => 2c3e260bb766ea1519dcbc3d13025d3ede6e2e63+mSfAHUAPvmFefQbIArozzbQfY0IzZpAeTarpQsHHOseN+SD3xmmUWfUduVYWf7qVu1Rwo2XYIBSBTUt+J1DhbE9sN2yEelpjsHzU0CVw3F1aPpcPh6oSTzIfskr2hHuWIGi5sf1lvD7qRHtcjPOBD700vnQSy2+DIMTNT4eMS7pz85zi9TMpgLQfWbtUUtNQk1SRHwncwgQyp1xhgPqp4d6eLjaZQ2hXBtOgYbC2Ty5xS4e76WCW+dumNMj3hkSfMoDssKnmRTzV7jYUT6a+oH26tZkKOR8EMMh04xHMWlt73aFsL9EZrIXZFKHkOXqU883qThWot//emOpakBKWyA== [laravel_session] => 2729bdfca6fe6e6f3c98d03c11a65915649af09b+ML1G6xZ5YkImViUxm9gOaTo5AT8jyBfqagdoeyAs ) 1
```

Update:

I really don't know why this was voted down but here,

I want to access the cookie using JS previously added using PHP.

Comment: Maybe you're using it wrong. Maybe there's a bug. Maybe there's some fundamentally wrong condition. Impossible to say with the little information given.

Comment: check cookie expiration date? and try `alert(document.cookie)` in your JS to see cookie values.

Comment: @deceze what else do you need? i set a cookie using php n want to read using js?

Comment: @muthukumaran its for that session using 0

Comment: Show some code? Both for how the cookie is set and how it's read. Have you tried using pure Javascript, without jQuery?

Comment: What do you get when you `print_r($_COOKIE);` in PHP?

Comment: @deceze i just updated the code

Comment: @GeertJaminon i get some random encrypted stuff let me update

Answer (score 1):

If COOKIE expiry set to 0, the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes). So, JS will not read expired COOKIEs

Try setting the COOKIE expiration for longer,

```
Cookie::put('id', $id , time()+3600, '/'); //set the cookie alive for 1 hour
```

Comment: But thats my req. that a cookie / session should expire once the browser closes. The cookie holds info. for login.